# Laravel Cashier (Stripe) Custom Webhook not receiving $payload

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

We are trying to create a custom webhook to handle Stripe Checkout with Laravel Cashier. The problem is that we are following Laravel Cashier docs, but we are not receiving the payload from Stripe.

We are trying to hook to `checkout.session.completed`.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController as CashierController;

class StripeWebhookController extends CashierController
{

    /**
     * Handle Checkout Session Completed.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handleCheckoutSessionCompleted(array $payload) // Line 12
    {
    // Code...
    }
```

```php
// Error: ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\StripeWebhookController::handleCheckoutSessionCompleted(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected in file /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/StripeWebhookController.php on line 12
```

We also created the route in `web.php`

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\StripeWebhookController;

Route::post('/stripe/webhook', [StripeWebhookController::class, 'handleCheckoutSessionCompleted']);
```

We did add inside `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

```php
protected $except = [
    'stripe/*',
];
```

Finally we also added our webhook secret inside the `.env` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```php
Route::post('/stripe/webhook', [StripeWebhookController::class, 'handleCheckoutSessionCompleted']);
```

for

```php
Route::post('/stripe/webhook', [StripeWebhookController::class, 'handleWebhook']);
```